# How do I automate inserting a specific date on a web page that will change weekly?

Tags: javascript, automation

I have a task that I do where it is the same thing over and over. I want to see if I can automate this by just making it a single click say from a Bookmark tab using Javascript.

So basically what I am doing is:
Step 1- Go to a web page
Step 2- Click on a link to go to a certain area into the web page
Step 3- Click on another link to go into a certain area within the area in the web page
Step 4 - Add specific past date and add a new current date
Step 5- Click submit

After doing this I then have to do this 5 times in total:
Step 1- Go to a link and click on that link
Step 2- Click on a drop down arrow
Step 3- Click on an edit button
Step 4- Enter a specific date in a specific area
Step 5- Click submit

Repeat the following process 4 more times in 4 separate links

I have tried to find the correct file path from the web URL. I have tried to see what functions in Javascript could create this kind of automation. I get to a certain point - getting to Step 3 in the first point of steps but can not go any further. I am stuck. Any help would be great!

javascript: d=document.location,l="https://"+d.host+"/webapps/date-management/daterollover/showDateRollover?action=display&course_id="+course_id+"&mode=quick",void(window.location=l);

Again I am only at step 3 in the first round of the process. I would like to try and get to a point where I can enter the date in an area for a single time then click a button and it will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please show us what you have tried so far by adding the code you've written. More information about asking can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: javascript: d=document.location,l="https://"+d.host+"/webapps/date-management/daterollover/showDateRollover?action=display&course_id="+course_id+"&mode=quick",void(window.location=l);

Comment: Again, please show us the code you have written so far. You mentioned that you are stuck at step 3, but the code you have shown is barely enough to complete step 1. What we need is some example HTML and the JS you've already written to complete the steps 1 & 2. And please add the code to your question instead of posting it as a comment.